# How to correctly print xml data from clob?

Tags: oracle

For example,  my clob contains xml content as shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<content>
<foo>bar</foo>
<bar>foo</bar>
</content>
```

When i print it using loop, struct of content is not well-formed.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`XMLSerialize`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions239.htm#SQLRF52025) function:

```
with test_data as (
  select
    '<?xml version="1.0"?><content>
     <foo>bar</foo><bar>foo</bar></content>' as x_data
  from dual
)
select
  xmlserialize(document xmltype(x_data) as clob indent size = 2) x_text
from test_data
```

[**<kbd>SQLFiddle</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/30249)